# send email reminder for manually flagged emails (with reminders) via VBA in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking for a outlook vba code which can send an email to the recipients where I have marked the particular email as a follow up and with an reminder

this could be manually or it could have been send along with the email

currently I have checked many codes on the internet however have got solutions for those emails which have been booked as an appointment (worked well) however I need to send a reminder to those Emails which are flagged by me (with reminders) and when outlook pop that reminder up it should populate an email to their recipients as well (email body could be hardcoded).

Answer (score 0):

First, assign a handler to the reminder, we can use two way for this:

**Way A**(need to put on the ThisOutlookSession):

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
'Updated by ExtendOffice 20180814
Dim xAppointment As AppointmentItem
If Item.Class = olAppointment Then
    Set xAppointment = Item
    MsgBox xAppointment.Subject, 4096 + vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Outlook reminders"
End If
End Sub
```

**Way B**: Create a module, and add the following code to the module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rHandler As TestHandler

' #############
' Hook up the mail reply..
' #############
Public Sub HookTest()
    Set rHandler = New TestHandler
    Set rHandler.myExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set rHandler.objReminders = Application.reminders
    rHandler.ForceSelectionChange
End Sub

' #############
' Unhook the mail reply.
' #############
Public Sub UnhookTest()
    Set rHandler = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Then**, handle the logic in the handler（Create a class module name it to TestHandler, which will be used in the **assign way B**）, I will create a handler for the way B. Handle the **item_PropertyChange** event for “flag action" and handle the send mail to recipients in the **ReminderFire**

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mItem As MailItem
Public WithEvents objReminders As Outlook.reminders
Public WithEvents myExplorer As Explorer

' #########
' destructor.
' #########
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If Not (mItem Is Nothing) Then
        Set mItem = Nothing
    End If

    If Not (myExplorer Is Nothing) Then
        Set myExplorer = Nothing
    End If


    If Not (objReminders Is Nothing) Then
        Set objReminders = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub mItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
 'to do sth
End Sub 

' ##################################################
' Event: Occurs when you select another or more Microsoft Outlook items.
' ##################################################
Private Sub myExplorer_SelectionChange()
    Dim mySel As Selection

    Set mySel = myExplorer.Selection

    ' /* There is only one item in the browser window that is selected. */
    If mySel.Count = 1 Then
        Dim objItem As Object

        Set objItem = mySel.Item(1)

        ' /* The selected item is a mail. */
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            ' /* Dynamically register the event of a message */
            Set mItem = objItem
        End If
    End If

    Set mySel = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
End Sub

' #####################################
' Forces the selected item in the browser window to change the event.
' #####################################
Public Sub ForceSelectionChange()
    Call myExplorer_SelectionChange
End Sub


Private Sub objReminders_ReminderFire(ByVal ReminderObject As Reminder)
ReminderObject.Item.Display
' to do send mail
End Sub
```

Comment: hI @ 
Seiya Su 

I tried compying pasting this in "thisoutlook session gave me an error Compile error - subject or function not defined..

could you check

Comment: The code no compile error on my side, but while use the github editor to format code, there are some error. Maybe cased by this . And i still try how to get recipient list. But time limited, I don't have time do it now.  I am not suggest to use the ThisOutlookSession way(In my answer it is Way A). I prefer to Way B. In wayB, we need a Module and a class module, have updated the code comment.

Comment: hi sorry I did not understand the way b method. please could you guide me with steps

Comment: First, create a class module in the Outlook VB editor. Copy-Paste the code i have provided. And then create a module then Copy-Paste the code from WayB assign.

Comment: To use the hook/unhook, just clich teh Macro list

Comment: WithEvents way is the key of B way. I am not sure the official definition, but it works well for most case.

Comment: hi see below reply - which i have send